# Regex to match paths that don't match a specific pattern: Express Router

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I want to ignore all paths of the form /foo/* on my express server. 
So I want to do

```
app.get('someRegexThatDoesntMatchFoo/*', routes.index)
```

I have tried

```
app.get('/^\(\(.*foo/.*\)\@!.\)*$', routes.index);
```

but that didnt work-- it doesn't catch `all-routes-besides-foo` and apply `routes.index` instead i get a `CANNOT GET bar` for any `/bar` request

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing much about the paths that you will be receiving this should be done using negative assertions (lookaheads/lookbehinds)

Comment: What regex language is that?

Comment: For most lang's a simple /foo/\*(?!)$ will fail for the string.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will match any path except those starting with /foo/

```
app.get(/^\/([^f][^o][^o]|.{1,2}|.{4,})\/.*$/, routes.index);
```

I assume that this is a standard javascript regex.

Comment: You have the right idea, but JavaScript doesn't support look-behinds ([yet](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:regexp_look-behind_support)). Look-aheads are fine: `/^\/(?!foo(\/|$)).*$/`

Answer (score 3):

The first answer was not correct, that's why I post again.

#### Solution

The following regex will match any path except those starting with /foo/

```
app.get(/^\/([^f]|f[^o]|fo[^o]|foo[^/]).*$/, routes.index);
```

This solution gets more and more complex as the size of the string increases.

#### Recommended

Anyway, looking here for a regex is not the right thing.

When configuring routes, you have always to start with the more special rule and finish with the most general. Like this you would not run in such issues.

You first have to define your route for `/foo/*` and after that for all others `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Define a route for `/foo/*` to handle (or not), then use a wildcard to handle everything else.

```
app.get('/foo/*', function(req,res) {
  //ignore or handle
});

app.get('*', routes.index);
```

Comment: what does "ignore" look like? it would just hang the server if we leave that function empty right?...

Comment: I'm not sure what your app is, but you do have options for how you'd like to handle that. Just putting a `return;` statement will cause the app to hang, or you could redirect, or send an error message with corresponding status code. If you do just want to send nothing, you could use `res.end();`.

Answer (score 2):

Negative lookahead regexps work (at least in modern times):

```
app.get(/^(?!\/foo\/)/, routes.index);
```

Comment:  Thank you that's what I was looking for 